# How to add vertex id as property in Gremlin

Tags: tinkerpop, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, gremlin-java

Due to an application design fault, I need to add vertex_id as the `property` of the vertex. How to do that in Gremlin Query?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! The below query is working....

```
g.V().hasLabel('user').as('user').V().hasLabel('user')
.where(eq('user')).as('u_id').property('user_id', select('u_id').id())
```